# Ratio of the total energy of the beta particle to its rest energy

Tags: particle-physics

I'm trying to learn particle physics and I came across this question in which I have no idea on what to do. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Uranium-239 decays by emitting a beta particle, to Neptunium. The energy released in this decay is 1.29 MeV.

Q. **Find the ratio of the total energy of the beta particle to its rest energy is equal to the 'gamma factor' for the particle, calculate this value. (me = 0.511 MeV / c^2)**

P.S - The answer is 3.53

Comment: You have two particles. Conserve energy and (relativistic) momentum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$U^{239}\rightarrow Ne^{239}+\beta^-+Q$

$ Q=1.29 [MeV]$
$m_ec^2=0.511[MeV] $

$\Gamma =\frac{1.29+0.511}{0.511}=3.52$

Q is the kinetic energy released in the decay, which distributes between the electron and the Neptunium nuclei. At certain occasions all of this energy transferred to the beta particle in the lab frame of reference. (And by these events you actually measure in the lab the Q value of the decay)